# Customizing indexes in songs package

Tags: formatting, indexing, songs

I'm going to build a songbook with the "songs" package. I already did some formatting to fit the songbook to my needs.

Now I'm going to customize the indexes of the songbook. In a title-index

```
\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\indexsongsas{titleidx}{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\songchapter}{\chapter*}
[...]
\showindex{Title index}{titleidx}
```

I want to add the author of the song to each entry.

Actually it's looking like, e. g.:

```
Lady in Black ..................... 4
Lemon Tree ........................ 6
```

But I want it to look like, e. g.:

```
Lady in Black (Uriah Heep) ........ 4
Lemon Tree (Fool's Garden) ........ 6
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?! :) I hope it's clear, I can't upload images right now. :(

Thank you very much and best wishes!

// Edit: Full Example (using the latest songs package).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\geometry{a4paper, top=15mm, left=20mm, right=20mm, bottom=22.5mm, headsep=2.5mm, footskip=5mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}

\renewcommand{\lyricfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\sffamily}

\songcolumns{1}
\songpos{0}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\indexsongsas{titleidx}{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\idxtitlefont}{\sffamily\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\showindex{Title index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{Lady In Black}[by={Uriah\ Heep}]
  \beginverse*
    {\nolyrics Intro: \[Em Em]}
  \endverse
  \beginverse
    \memorize
    She \[Em]came to me one morning, one \[Em]lonely Sunday morning
    Her \[D]long hair flowing in the \[Em]mid-winter wind
    I \[Em]know not how she found me, for in \[Em]darkness I was walking
    And de\[D]struction lay around me, from a \[Em]fight I could not win
    \[Em]Ahh Ahh Ahh \[D]Ahh \[Em]Ahh ... \[Em]Ahh \[D]Ahh \[Em]Ahh \[Em] \[Em] \[Em]
  \endverse
  \beginverse*
    ...
  \endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Lemon Tree}[by={Fool's\ Garden}]
  \beginverse*
    \nolyrics{Intro: \[Em] ~ \[Bm] ~ \[Em] ~ \[Bm] ~ \[Am] ~ \[Bm] ~ \[Em]}
  \endverse
  \beginverse
    I'm \[Em]sitting here in the \[Bm]boring room
    It's \[Em]just another rainy Sunday \[Bm]afternoon
    I'm \[Em]wasting my time, I got \[Bm]nothing to do
    I'm \[Em]hanging around, I'm \[Bm]waiting for you
    But \[Am]nothing ever happens \[Bm] and I \[Em]wonder
  \endverse
  \beginverse*
    ...
  \endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

// Edit 2:
Oh, there is another, maybe easy to solve, problem: I want to change the (1-column) width of the "Title Index". Actually it's not wide enough, some entries are broken by the end of line. Any idea?! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My humble¹ attempt follows. `:)`

The idea here is to patch the line responsible for indexing the title song in the `.sdx` file. The steps:

- Add the title for the current song, defined in `\songtitle`.
- Check if there are authors for the current song by issuing a conditional on `\songauthors`.
- If there are no authors (`\ifx\songauthors\empty`), do nothing.
- If we have authors (`\else` branch), typeset them inside parentheses.

Instead of redefining the whole macro, let's use the amazing `xpatch` package to ease our lives. We will use `\xpatchcmd` on `\SB@@@beginsong`, which contains the line we need to alter.

The patch:

```
\xpatchcmd{\SB@@@beginsong}
  {\SB@addtoindexes\songtitle}
  {\SB@addtoindexes{\songtitle\ifx\songauthors\empty\else\ (\songauthors)\fi}}
  {}{}
```

The full example (I took the liberty of removing some of your original packages in order to make the example more concise, I hope you don't mind):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SB@@@beginsong}
  {\SB@addtoindexes\songtitle}
  {\SB@addtoindexes{\songtitle\ifx\songauthors\empty\else\ (\songauthors)\fi}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\indexsongsas{titleidx}{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\showindex{Title index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{Lady In Black}[by={Uriah\ Heep}]
  \beginverse*
    ...
  \endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Lemon Tree}[by={Fool's\ Garden}]
  \beginverse*
    ...
  \endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Orange Tree}
  \beginverse 
   ...
  \endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

If we take a look at the index, we will have:

[image]

Hope it helps. `:)`

**Update:** As you figured out by yourself, `\showindex` has an optional argument that specifies the number of columns. According to the package source, `\showindex` is defined as

```
\newcommand\showindex[3][0]{%
```

so the default number of columns is actually `0`. Supplying `1` to the macro's optional argument will do the job.

---

¹ As egreg brilliantly reminded me in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10212051#10212051), it's very dangerous to use the word *humble* when Uriah Heep is involved. `:)` This is a reference to Charles Dickens' famous novel *David Cooperfield*, where Uriah Heep always professes his (false) humbleness. `:)` Of course, in the context of this answer, we have *another* Uriah Heep, which is an English rock band; curiously, they have an album named *Very 'eavy, very 'umble* which was their debut. `:)` Now back to our normal schedule. `:P`

[image: Duck]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. That's it. It's exactly what I tried to get on my own. :)

Comment: Oh, there is another, maybe easy to solve, problem: I want to change the (1-column) width of the "Title Index". Actually it's not wide enough, some entries are broken by the end of line.

Any idea?! :)